# Did Latin have the same gender labels that the Romance languages have?

Tags: language-evolution, gender, romance-languages

I'm curious about the concept and origin of gendered nouns. In a modern romance language such as Spanish, nouns are masculine or feminine which I'll describe as anthropomorphic labels. From my schoolboy Latin, I recall the declensions but not gender (it was a very long time ago). From a little research I've learned Latin had the concept of gendered adjectives, but my question is were they even then referred to using the same anthropomorphic labels as today, ie. masculine/feminine, or were they simply type A or type B with the anthropomorphic connotations grafted on later.

Comment: No offense, but this is truly a new record in the discipline of "I had Latin in school, but have forgotten most of it" 

Comment: @SebastianKoppehel it was a veeeery long time ago

Comment: [Dyirbal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dyirbal_language#Grammar) has a system of 4 noun classes that are analogous to gender. **1. most animate objects, men 2. women, water, fire, violence, and exceptional animals 3. edible fruit and vegetables 4. everything else.** If you combine this with some of the other answers, it seems clear that gendered nouns are widespread.

Comment: Is your question whether both Spanish and Latin have noun genders?
Or is it about whether popular words like (say) "water" are of the same gender in Spanish and Latin?

Comment: Does [this](https://dannybate.com/2021/03/15/the-decline-and-fall-of-the-latin-neuter/) comprehensive introduction to differences between Latin and Romance languages grammatical gender answer what you actually want to know?

Answer (score 23):

Yes, Latin had a distinction between masculine and feminine nouns (and also a third category, "neuter"). This didn't always correspond to biology—*homo* "human" is always masculine, even when referring to a woman, and *persona* "person" is always feminine, even when referring to a man—but most words for humans and animals match their gender to their referent's.

Of course, most nouns *don't* describe humans and animals, and there's nothing especially male or female about water, roads, the sky, etc. So we could just call them "category A" and "category B" (and "category C") if we wanted. But it helps to have more memorable labels, and one of the most consistent rules about this is that names for men tend to be masculine and names for women tend to be feminine. (Though even this has exceptions!) As a result, since ancient times there's been a convention to refer to these categories as "masculine" and "feminine" (and "neuter").

The origin seems to go all the way back to Proto-Indo-European. It's likely that, originally, there were only two categories, "animate" and "inanimate", and this is the system we find in e.g. Hittite. But at some point, a special marking was devised for female humans and animals, and this split the "animate" category into "default/masculine" and "feminine".

It's hard to say any more than this with certainty, because it happened so long ago and evidence is scarce. But it's true that most Indo-European languages treat the masculine as the default gender for humans, and the feminine as the unusual or marked one. (For example, a group of men and women together will usually take a masculine adjective.) It would make sense if this came from the feminine gender being split off at a later point, compared to the masculine and neuter.

Comment: To be even more explicit, [Quintilian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quintilian) used expressions like *masculinum nomen* (masculine noun) and *masculinum genus* (masculine gender). Interestingly, though, *masculinum* does not appear to be attested in this sense before him.

Comment: @SebastianKoppehel True! Though of course the terminology doesn't start with him; he's calquing the Greek names used by Dionysius Thrax.

Comment: @SebastianKoppehel that's actually the answer I was looking for. Many thanks

Comment: I can’t remember where I’ve read it, so I might misremember it (please correct me then; also if you know sources I’d be grateful if you provided them), but isn’t there a theory that the inanimate split into neuter and feminine, the latter being the collective and/or abstract version of the neuter? I think it shows in how neutral plural coincides with feminine singular. Also neuter being the same in nominative and accusative in IE languages seems to come from the fact that the inanimate could not be the subject of a sentence in the beginning.

Comment: @dlrlc It's possible; what we see in Anatolian is an animate-inanimate split (though the labels aren't entirely accurate there either—grain is animate) where animate nouns have nominative and accusative cases and neuter nouns have ergative and absolutive instead. If this reflects an earlier state in IE, that would explain why neuter nouns' nominatives and accusatives always look the same. But even if this does indicate that the feminine was a later development (and it may not; some people argue that Anatolian merged m-f due to sound change) it's hard to pinpoint how exactly it arose.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proto-Indo-European_nominals#Gender says "The feminine ending is thought to have developed from a collective/abstract suffix \**-h₂* that also gave rise to the neuter collective."

Comment: @Draconis Japanese does not have strongly gendered adjectives (in the sense of being very highly marked when used by a particular group and much less marked when used by another), but うまい "tasty" is probably more common in masculine speech (or at least connotes a kind of roughness or informality more associated with men).

Comment: @jogloran That's very different from grammatical gender, though. Even English has that: women are "beautiful" and men are "handsome", for example. Grammatical gender is merely a categorization of words, though, and there's no special relationship between it and sex. The German word for "young woman" is Mädchen, which is neuter, not feminine.

Comment: Draconis appears to have deleted the comment I was responding to. They were asking about whether Japanese has gendered adjectives — I assumed they did not mean grammatical gender, as it's well known that Japanese doesn't have that.

Comment: @jogloran Another moderator deleted the whole exchange; someone referenced Japanese having gender on adjectives, I asked what they were referring to, and they clarified they misspoke and were referring to gendered pronouns.

Comment: _Homo_ can indeed take feminine agreement, especially if the referent is a real person known to be female; but, as I understand it, the usage is uncommon.

Answer (score 4):

Most<sup>1</sup> [Afroasiatic Languages also have noun gender](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Afroasiatic_languages#Nouns). This appears to indicate it was likely a common feature of Proto-Afroasiatic, and not borrowed later from contact with Indo-European. I'm not sure about the research on how the use of their grammatical gender may have changed over time, but it seems safe to speculate that the features that are common in all branches haven't changed *that* much since those branches diverged.

In Proto Indo-European, it seems like the grammatical gender may have originally have been more of an [animated-vs.-inanimate designator](https://allegatifac.unipv.it/silvialuraghi/Gender%20FoL.pdf)<sup>(PDF)</sup>. However, the "animate" nouns seem to have split into genders (leaving us with masculine, feminine, and neuter) before Romance/Latin developed its own identity. The best guess for the change seems to be sometime after Anatolian split off. That's sometime around 4kBCE, or about 3,000 years before Latin's [Italic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Italic_languages) became its own family.

[image]

---

<sup>1 - According to Frajzyngier et. al. [The Afroasiatic Languages](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0521865336), all branches but not all languages of the Afroasiatic language family have gendered nouns.</sup>

Comment: While the original title was unclear, I believe (and OP seems to confirm in comments) that he's looking more about the terminology of gendered nouns in Latin and Romance languages.